# How to fix " Gitlab windows ci runner: ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException"

Tags: python, windows, shell, powershell, gitlab-ci-runner

I can able to set the ci runner for windows but unable configure the git lab ci runner with `cmd executor` and by defaultci runner executor is `POWER SHELL ISE`

How to change config the executor from `power shell-ise` to `cmd`

I have tried with below config.toml file, same error.

```
executor = "shell"
shell = "cmd"
```

```
Git revision: dd63573f
Git branch:   master
GO version:   go1.8.7
Built:        2019-08-13T10:51:28+0000
OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
```

what is the gitlab-ci windows runner version for supported cmd version ...?

Comment: I am getting same error. di you found any solution?